# How to debug DXA Model Service

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, model-service

I am trying to solve an issue were the JSON output of the DXA Model Service contains un-escaped RTF content breaking the JSON object. I would like build and debug the code of the [DXA Model Service](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service).

I am able to build the code, however it is not clear to me how to configure IntelliJ IDEA so I can attach the debugger to the Service Container.

Does anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: Take a look at this answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process

Comment: Or check out this blog: http://blog.trivident.com/running-the-tridion-deployer-in-your-ide/. It's about the deployer, not the model service but you may be able to take some pointers from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos to Velmurugan; following his suggestion I found that debugging of the DXA Model Service is very straight forward by using the remote debugging feature. It's a 2 step process:

1. Configuring remote debugging in IntelliJ IDEA
   [image: remote debugging configuration]
2. Add remote debugging JVM parameters to the start script of the DXA Model Service
   [image]

Nice benefit of using remote debugging instead of trying to run the application within the IDE, is that you can debug the DXA Model Service from any environment, provided you add the JVM parameters to the start script.